# Batch file for AWS polly fails after aws polly synthesize-speech

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, batch-rename, windows-server-2016, amazon-polly

I have a batch file that has the following statements

```
 aws polly synthesize-speech --output-format mp3 --text-type ssml --voice-id Joanna --text "<speak><prosody pitch='medium' rate='medium'>Test, User, #26</prosody></speak>" temp.mp3
 rename temp.mp3 4243.mp3
 move /Y 4243.mp3 ./Te 
 aws polly synthesize-speech --output-format mp3 --text-type ssml --voice-id Joanna --text "<speak>Francis Goldney</speak>" temp.mp3
 rename temp.mp3 3035.mp3
 move /Y 3035.mp3 ./Fr
```

The command prompt looks like this.

Note that the temp.mp3 was created. It just stops running after that.

I tried checking `%errorlevel%` and it was 0

**Edit**

Now without screenshot

```
 D:\sites\xxxx.com\beta\scheduler\polly\media>_polly.bat

 D:\sites\xxxx.com\beta\scheduler\polly\media>del temp.mp3

 D:\sites\xxxx.com\beta\scheduler\polly\media>aws polly synthesize-speech --output-format mp3 --text-type ssml --voice-id Joanna --text "<speak><prosody pitch='medium' rate='medium'>Test, User, #26</prosody></speak>" temp.mp3
 audio/mpeg      15
```

End of processing

Comment: Please don't post screen snaps. Post an [MCVE] and include the textual output copied from the console window (select, copy, paste, edit out whatever secrets it contains, copy and paste to your question.  It's just not obvious which temp.mp3 file was created or was it both?  Better to post the entire textual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was not the aws polly that was the problem. It was the move operation. When the file was created via aws polly, there was not enough permission to move it.

This issue was solved when I just created the file in the target location and not try move it after creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution to this. Instead of a line like this:

```
aws polly synthesize-speech --output-format "ogg_vorbis" --text "Hello." --voice-id "Salli" hello.ogg
```

run it through python like this:

```
python.exe -m awscli polly synthesize-speech --output-format "ogg_vorbis" --text "Hello." --voice-id "Salli" hello.ogg
```

Then it will acknowledge every single line. I think the problem is that aws.cmd is formatted in a way that takes all subsequent lines as part of the same argument.

Comment: This would mean I would have to do a ColdFusion to Python integration

Comment: Or the aws.cmd file that parses the arguments needs to be fixed somehow.